# Deleting a line in multiple files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, delete-row

i am a beginner in python and i am practicing at the moment.

So what I want to do is a script that finds a line that I am writing with raw_input and that will search this line in multiple files and delete it.
Something like this but for more files:

```
word = raw_input("word: ")
f = open("file.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("file.txt","w")
for line in lines:
  if line!=mail+"\n":
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

It's an easy task but it's actually hard for me since I can't find an example anywhere.

Comment: do you mean `if line!=word+"\n"` ?

Comment: yes, sorry, it was mail before word and i forgot to change it :)

Comment: `delete-row`?  This has nothing to do w/ databases.

Comment: What are the multiple files? Are they all in the same directory? Do you want to delete a line if it is an exact match to `word` or if it contains `word`? Give an example of two or three sample files and how you would expect them to look after being processed.

Comment: multiple text files, in the same directory, to delete the exact word(any word i want) that i am typing it with raw_input

Comment: Example:this mail 'trust@yahoo.com' that is in multiple files, i want to delete it from each file if it exists there

Comment: Just fyi, `sed` is much better suited for what you are doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reading the entire file into memory, you should iterate through the file and write the lines that are OK to a temporary file. Once you've gone through the entire file, delete it and rename the temporary file to the name of the original file. This is a classic pattern that you'll most likely frequently encounter in the future.

I'd also recommend breaking this down into functions. You should first write the code for removing all occurrences of a line from only a single file. Then you can write another function that simply iterates through a list of filenames and calls the first function (that operates on individual files).

To get the filenames of the all the files in the directory, use `os.walk`. If you do not want to apply this function to all of the files in the directory, you can set the `files` variable yourself to store whatever configuration of filenames you want.

```
import os


def remove_line_from_file(filename, line_to_remove, dirpath=''):
    """Remove all occurences of `line_to_remove` from file
    with name `filename`, contained at path `dirpath`.
    If `dirpath` is omitted, relative paths are used."""
    filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
    temp_path = os.path.join(dirpath, 'temp.txt')

    with open(filename, 'r') as f_read, open(temp_path, 'w') as temp:
        for line in f_read:
            if line.strip() == line_to_remove:
                continue
            temp.write(line)

    os.remove(filename)
    os.rename(temp_path, filename)


def main():
    """Driver function"""
    directory = raw_input('directory: ')
    word = raw_input('word: ')

    dirpath, _, files = next(os.walk(directory))

    for f in files:
        remove_line_from_file(f, word, dirpath)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**TESTS**

All of these files are in the same directory. On the left is what they looked like before running the command, on the right is what they look like afterwards. The "word" I input was `Remove this line`.

*a.txt*

```
Foo                                           Foo
Remove this line                              Bar
Bar                                           Hello
Hello                                         World
Remove this line
Remove this line
World
```

*b.txt*

```
Nothing                                       Nothing
In                                            In
This File                                     This File
Should                                        Should
Be Changed                                    Be Changed
```

*c.txt*

```
Remove this line
```

*d.txt*

```
The last line will be removed                 The last line will be removed
Remove this line
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Mailuri Mari\junk.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Mailuri Mari\junk.py", line 26, in main
    dirpath, _, files = os.walk(directory)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: Whoops... that was a mistake on my part. Should be fixed now!

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not working :\ i have 2 lines in different files and none has been deleted

Comment: That's what I get for not thoroughly testing my code :P. Anyway, I just fixed it and it is working beautifully now. I included some tests I ran so you can see for yourself. Sorry about that, once again!

Comment: I appreciate your work, but this is what i'm getting now :)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Mailuri Mari\junk.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Mailuri Mari\junk.py", line 26, in main
    dirpath, _, files = next(os.walk(directory))
StopIteration

Comment: @NitaAlexandru That's because the directory you entered does not exist. Try entering the absolute path. Also if there are "strange" characters in the path, you might need to escape them.

Comment: oho now it works awesome :D but what if i want to get multiple words written in a file and delete them from the the other files?

Comment: @NitaAlexandru I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. Could you please clarify? If it is a very different requirement it is probably best for you to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: for example i have a file full of words, and some other files that i want those words to be deleted from. Instead of manually writing every word that i want to be deleted, i want something that extracts all the words from that file and delete them automatically from the other files

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work:

```
source = '/some/dir/path/'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for f in filenames:
        this_file = open(os.path.join(source, f), "r")
        this_files_data = this_file.readlines()
        this_file.close()
        # rewrite the file with all line except the one you don't want
        this_file = open(os.path.join(source, f), "w")
        for line in this_files_data:
            if line != "YOUR UNDESIRED LINE HERE":
                this_file.write(line)
        this_file.close()
```